# How to delete & deploy EAR archives in WinSCP?

Tags: linux, java, winscp

I have a *folder* called XYZ.ear (folder icon) deployed in the server through WinScp.
I want to delete this and also deploy a new *ear* file instead of the above *folder*.

Is there any specific command that I use in the putty or should I just drag 'n' drop?
By dragging 'n' dropping will the *ear* change into a folder str automatically?

Comment: Any answers fellows? I am quite held up with this.

Comment: Do you want to automate this task or are you looking for manual solution using GUI?

Comment: Looking for manual solution only. Thank you for the response

Answer (score 1):

The EAR file won't extract automatically when transferred (dropped on remote panel of WinSCP).

You need to either:

- Extract it locally and then upload whole directory structure;
- Or upload the EAR archive and extract it in the remote directory. Note that the `.ear` file is actually a ZIP archive. So you can extract it with the `unzip`. You can [remotely execute](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/remote_command) the `unzip` command from WinSCP directly. If you are going to do this often, you can setup a [custom command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/custom_commands) `unzip "!"`. Of course, you can also type the `unzip` command in PuTTY console.